# How can I link up my Firebase CDN snippet to my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't link the function below to my JavaScript file. I am using Firebase CDN code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

Firebase snippet:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAPeU7jO2Zz5kdrh-4g4ehfcrL8Aufzubs",
    authDomain: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40",
    storageBucket: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "941299603483",
    appId: "1:941299603483:web:afcd4f1da6878b51ef80be",
    measurementId: "G-BRYW3TQNLL"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.analytics();


js file:
db.collection('recipes').get().then((snapshot)=>{
    console.log(snapshot);

}).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err)
});
```

The error msg is:

> sandbox.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function at sandbox.js:1 (anonymous) @ sandbox.js:1

Comment: The erro msg is sandbox.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at sandbox.js:1
(anonymous) @ sandbox.js:1

Comment: You're pulling in the analytics file from the CDN but it looks like you're attempting to use firestore.

Answer (score 0):

The `db` variable from the `script` tag in your HTML file is not automatically available in the `.js` file.

You'll typically want to put all JavaScript (including what you now have in the `script` tag into the `.js` file **or** have all of it in the `script` tag in the HTML file.

Putting all code in the `.js` file is more common, so that'd become:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAPeU7jO2Zz5kdrh-4g4ehfcrL8Aufzubs",
  authDomain: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40",
  storageBucket: "udemy-modern-javascript-cee40.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "941299603483",
  appId: "1:941299603483:web:afcd4f1da6878b51ef80be",
  measurementId: "G-BRYW3TQNLL"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.analytics();

db.collection('recipes').get().then((snapshot)=>{
  console.log(snapshot);
}).catch(err =>{
  console.log(err)
});

const db = firebase.analytics();
```